# Dividing list of integers into alternating groups of even and odd sums

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, math

Ok so lets pretend we have a list [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13], I want to make a python program which will divide the list into the maximum number of groups alternating between sums of even or odd. (Even always has to go first)
For example the list above can be divided into:

[1,3] , [5,7,9] , [11,13]
even ,   odd,  ,   even

If the list was:
[11, 2, 17, 13, 1, 15, 3]
we would have:

[2], [11], [13,1], [15], [17,3]

This way, we cannot further divide, and we have the maximum number of groups.
I have been thinking about various solutions, for example putting the evens first and then continuing with the groupings. My code so far divides the list of all the integers into a list of even integers and a list of odd integers.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to use the number of even and odd integers to calculate how many even and odd groups there should be in the final list.

**Edit:
The list can have any numbers less than 100 as long as they don't repeat, they are not necessarily consecutive.**

this is the structure I've been trying to use so far (its incomplete but you can look at it)

```
while True:
itera = []
if count % 2 == 0 and len(evens) > 0:
    x = evens[0]
    itera.append(x)
    lines.append(itera)
    evens.remove(x)
if count % 2 == 1 and len(odds) > 0:
    x = odds[0]
    itera.append(x)
    lines.append(itera)
    odds.remove(x)
if len(odds) == 0:
    if count % 2 == 1:
        print(count+1)

if len(evens) == 0:
    if count % 2 == 0:

    if count % 2 == 1 and len(odds) :
        print(count+1)
        
count+=1
if len(breeds) == 0:
    break
```

Really appreciated if someone could help out

Comment: how many groups can we make?

Comment: we need to find the maximum number of possible groups

Comment: Why the second group doesn't consist of only `5`? It's an odd number and can make an odd group by its own.

Comment: @John , order must be preserved, right?

Comment: use dp, maximum no of groups when all integer are different and equal no of even and odd, so then you can make max alternate groups, if there are differnet even or odd numbers then you can join them together to make a group having more than 1 element and follow this process for others

Comment: yup, so we need it to have even, odd, even... ect

Comment: if the second group had just 5 we would have to put 7 and 9 in the fourth and we cant have 2 evens in a row

Comment: @sahasrara62 can you elaborate on that? I know what you're saying on putting numbers together but how can we make sure that we are maximizing on the number of groups

Comment: So this has nothing to do with the actual values in the input list?  The input could just be `7` then for the example..."given 7 items in a list"?

Comment: we can have up to 100 items in the list and we have to find the maximum number of possible groups.

Comment: Is `[1, 3], [5], [7, 9, 11, 13]` a valid solution?

Comment: @sahasrara62 but we can also potentially have groups of 3 so how would we expand this?

Comment: yup @Steve thats a valid solution

Comment: I think I may be narrowing in on a solution.  If there were one less item, would `[1, 3], [5], [7, 9], [11]` be a valid solution?

Comment: yup that would be right

Comment: @John - Sorry that I took you off in the wrong direction.  I missed how the sum of the numbers played into the solution.  It just so happens that the samples I presented above fit both the real problem and my idea of what the problem was.  So you have a truly HARD problem here...much harder than I was making it out to be.  I'll think some more, but maybe someone smarter than me will have to come up with a solution.  Best of luck!

Comment: This question was in yesterday's USACO contest, and this question was asked yesterday. Coincidence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a few failures, I think I finally understand the problem and I think I have it. There are unsolvable cases for lists shorter than 4 elements, so the code below only tests cases with 4 elements and higher.

The first two test cases are the two presented at the top of the question. The next two test the two trivially degenerate cases...longer lists of all even or all odd values.  Then I do some random tests.

For the random tests, I try one list of each length from 4 to 14.  This doesn't necessarily test all the possible cases, because each case depends on the mix of even odd numbers, but it has a good chance to.  Also, you can run this over and over, and you get different results each time, but the results always seem to be correct.

```
import random

def do_it(input):

    print(input, ":\n    ", end="")

    r = []

    # Split the input into two groups, odds and evens
    odds = [n for n in input if n % 2]
    evens = [n for n in input if not n % 2]

    # First, add all of the trivial pairings of a single even and a single odd while we
    # still have one of each kind
    while len(odds) and len(evens):
        r.append([evens.pop(0)])
        r.append([odds.pop(0)])

    if len(odds):
        # If we now only have odd numbers...

        # Add trivial pairs of even then odd sums while we have 3 or more values
        while len(odds) > 2:
            r.append([odds.pop(0), odds.pop(0)])
            r.append([odds.pop(0)])
        if len(odds) == 2:
            # If we have two left over values, we're good, just create a final pair that will be even
            r.append([odds.pop(0), odds.pop(0)])
        elif len(odds):
            # We only have one odd. This is the strange case.  Here, we collapse the second and third
            # to last entries, which we can do because one of them is even and so the result will stay odd
            r[-3].extend(r.pop(-2))
            # Now the last entry is wrong because it is even but should now be odd.  But hey, we have one
            # last odd that we can add to it to change it from even to odd!  So we just do that.
            r[-1].append(odds.pop(0))
    elif len(evens):
        # If we now only have even numbers...

        # Add one last even value to the end of the list
        r.append([evens.pop(0)])
        # Now add the remaining evens to the last list.  We could add them to any of the
        # lists (or multiple lists), but just the last one is as good a choice as any.
        while len(evens):
            r[-1].append(evens.pop(0))

    print(r, "  (", len(r), ")")
    return r

print("Test cases given in question...")
do_it([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13])
do_it([11, 2, 17, 13, 1, 15, 3])
print()

print("Trivially degenerate cases...")
do_it([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35])
do_it([2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30])
print()

print("Random cases of increasing list length...")
for i in range(4, 15):
    do_it(random.sample(range(1, 100), i))
```

Sample run results:

```
Test cases given in question...
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13] :
    [[1, 3], [5, 7, 9], [11, 13]]   ( 3 )
[11, 2, 17, 13, 1, 15, 3] :
    [[2], [11], [17, 13], [1], [15, 3]]   ( 5 )

Trivially degenerate cases...
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35] :
    [[1, 3], [5], [7, 9], [11], [13, 15], [17], [19, 21], [23], [25, 27], [29], [31, 33], [35]]   ( 12 )
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30] :
    [[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30]]   ( 1 )

Random cases of increasing list length...
[14, 61, 88, 92] :
    [[14], [61], [88, 92]]   ( 3 )
[38, 98, 77, 87, 76] :
    [[38], [77], [98], [87], [76]]   ( 5 )
[71, 51, 45, 86, 56, 22] :
    [[86], [71], [56], [51], [22], [45]]   ( 6 )
[87, 16, 27, 52, 65, 77, 45] :
    [[16], [87], [52], [27], [65, 77], [45]]   ( 6 )
[84, 27, 13, 51, 58, 12, 46, 7] :
    [[84], [27], [58], [13], [12], [51], [46], [7]]   ( 8 )
[1, 65, 22, 41, 56, 18, 38, 69, 75] :
    [[22], [1], [56], [65], [18], [41, 38], [69, 75]]   ( 7 )
[34, 57, 18, 35, 40, 50, 43, 26, 44, 27] :
    [[34], [57], [18], [35], [40], [43], [50], [27], [26, 44]]   ( 9 )
[53, 47, 18, 17, 79, 36, 42, 31, 73, 92, 25] :
    [[18], [53], [36], [47], [42], [17], [92], [79], [31, 73], [25]]   ( 10 )
[19, 95, 35, 76, 60, 57, 58, 98, 46, 77, 26, 85] :
    [[76], [19], [60], [95], [58], [35], [98], [57], [46], [77], [26], [85]]   ( 12 )
[23, 86, 98, 56, 92, 82, 37, 36, 85, 12, 89, 94, 81] :
    [[86], [23], [98], [37], [56], [85], [92], [89], [82], [81], [36, 12, 94]]   ( 11 )
[86, 79, 74, 42, 50, 80, 75, 40, 97, 54, 66, 70, 60, 39] :
    [[86], [79], [74], [75], [42], [97], [50], [39], [80, 40, 54, 66, 70, 60]]   ( 9 )
```

Comment: @John - Am I right?  Do the numbers in the incoming list really not matter?  That's what I gathered.  I can change my code to sort the incoming list and put the actual numbers from the input into the groups, but that has nothing to do with the grouping logic.  If I'm right about them being independent, then do you see that? - If you just want to know the number of groups for any input size, this is giving you that without you having to worry about constructing a particular input list (since it doesn't matter).

Comment: wait so how would I use your code with my list of [11, 2, 17, 13, 1, 15, 3]. I mean this makes sense for the same list of consecutive odds but if we use something like the list I have I dont think it would work

Comment: I'll change my code if you want so that it does that.  It's a trivial change.  It's just harder to test and to demonstrate.  I chose not to do that because it doesn't matter to the logic of the code.

Comment: what im saying is that your code looks like its only for consecutive numbers but my input can be any numbers

Comment: Yeah, I get it.  Look at the addition I just made to my answer.  I'm still working on combining the two by producing random lists of numbers...

Comment: your code is starting from odd again in this example and starting from even in [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
7:  [['1', '3'], ['5'], ['7', '9', '11', '13']] (3) the result is always supposed to start from even

Comment: @John - Huh?  The first grouping is 2 items, which is even. - if the actual numbers in the list matter, how do they matter?

Comment: the sum has to be even

Comment: one of the examples was If the list was: [11, 2, 17, 13, 1, 15, 3] we would have: [2], [11], [13,1], [15], [17,3] as our result. the sum of the first group have to be even, the sum of the second have to be odd.

Comment: Oops.  Ok, then never mind;  My solution is too simple then.  I asked early on how the list contents mattered, and missed that the sum mattered too.  Sorry/.  I took a shot, but went off in the wrong direction :(

Comment: I hate to give up.  So I didn't.  @John, please take a look at the latest version of. my answer and see if it fits the bill.

Comment: wow damn you actually did it. I mean I'm prolly not big brain enough for this level of organization in a program like this but I really like the way you structured your code. Either way thanks so much!

Comment: No problem.  Obviously, I have too much time on my hands, LOL!  I just attacked the problem step by step.  The main revelation was that you never needed to make a sum list longer than minimally necessary, so I just keep trying to do the right thing with the minimum number of values.  Once I can't do that trivially, I then handle the special cases.  The only crazy case is what to do with a final odd entry when the next entry needs to be even.  That was the fun case that took a little extra thinking.  Glad I could help.  Feel free to give this the Green Check once you're sure it works

Comment: Look at the last test result.  It's an example of the most degenerate case...lots of even numbers...and it is still correct I believe.

Comment: @John.- no problem.  Done.  Also, note that I added a couple of simple degenerate cases to the code and the results.  (And also some headings in the results).  I wanted to make sure that both worked, and it's good to show them anyway...mostly how all even numbers results in only a single list in the result, as there's no way to make an odd sum.

Comment: Nice job Steve*, I had a slow day at work and was working on it there and while we were moving in similar directions you beat me to it. Emailed it to myself to work on it at home, but it looks like you've done it. It definitely ended up a little tougher than it seems at first glance. I was scared that someone was going to solve it with some itertools one liner lol.